# Editable email content for standard app users

Tags: python, django

Currently I have:

```
total_amount = Item.objects.get(user=self.request.user).total_amount
render_to_string('email/content.txt', {'total_amount ':   total_amount , })
```

content.txt:

> Hi User
>
> Your payment for ${{ total_amount }} will process within 48
>   hours.

but need separate setting page with form with email template like this:[image]

My try:

```
class Company(...):
   name = ...
   email_template = models.TextField

total_amount = Item.objects.get(user=self.request.user).total_amount
email_template = Company.objects.get(...).email_template
email_template = email_template.replace('{{ total_amount }}', total_amount)
email = EmailMessage()
email.message = email_template
...
email.send()
```

But what if user provide in form input different variable({{ total_amount }}) name that is incorrect? Is any way to secure this?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to build a json structure based on your user input. What I am saying is : for every input variable you can use  html tag and take input from the front-end and send that to the server code as a json structure.

For example 'total_amount' will be `input` html tag in your case and after submission the data will be send in following format.

```
{  'total_amount' : 34343, .....

}
```

And, process that at your server end.